# VBA to Insert Data in next available row that isn't the total row at the Bottom of the Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Workbooks that I need to copy/paste data from one workbook into the next available row in another workbook. The code I have below is almost working.  You see, there is a total row at the bottom of the destination workbook.  So, I'm trying to figure out how to insert a row at the next available row from the top, but instead, my code inserts the data below the totals row.

Here's how it looks in Excel.  I'm trying to insert what would be Row C, but instead it inserts below the "Totals" row:

Row A    1   2   3   4 
Row B    2   3   4   5 
<-----Trying to Insert Here---------->

Totals   3   5   7   9

Here's my code"
:

```
Sub sbCopyToDestination()
  
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Set SourceRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("f34:l34")

    Dim NextFreeCell As Range
    Set NextFreeCell = Workbooks("Destination.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1)

    SourceRange.Copy
    NextFreeCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code does not insert... It copies after the last row, like your code, as it is, should do. `Offset(RowOffset:=1)` means one row down from the last existing. Do you want inserting only in column B:C of the mentioned row to be inserted? I mean, the existing total will be pulled down only for these two columns. Or would you like to insert a whole row, and then copy the range in columns B:C of this new row?

Comment: For a final product, I want to insert a whole row.  And then copy the range of  f34 thru l34 are the columns with data in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It also updates the total, to include the pasted values.

```
    Dim SourceRange As Range, destSh As Worksheet, NextFreeCell As Range
    
    Set SourceRange = Range("f34:l34") ' ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("f34:l34")
    Set destSh = Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Workbooks("Destination.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set NextFreeCell = destSh.cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp)
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    NextFreeCell.EntireRow.Insert xlDown
    
    NextFreeCell.Offset(-1).Resize(, 2).Value = SourceRange.Value
    'if you do not need to update the sum formula with the new inserted row, coamment the next row
    NextFreeCell.Formula = UpdateFormula(NextFreeCell)
    NextFreeCell.Offset(, 1).Formula = UpdateFormula(NextFreeCell.Offset(, 1))

    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub

Function UpdateFormula(rng As Range) As String
   Dim x As String
   x = rng.Formula
   UpdateFormula = Replace(x, Split(x, ":")(1), _
       Replace(Split(x, ":")(1), rng.Row - 2, rng.Row - 1))
End Function
```

Comment: I like the insert way of doing this.  Very cool.  I tried this, and it's still inserting it after the total, which is the last row of the sheet.  I'm trying to get it to insert it after the last row of data, and before the row of totals.  How do I insert in between like that?  Is that possible?

Comment: @Susan T. This is more then strange... Try, please to manually insert a row. You will select it and the insertion will be produced above selection. The code, tested by me, inserts the row above the last one. Is it possible that you do not have a Total formula exactly on the B:B column, which is used to determine the last row? Anyhow, try changing of `Set NextFreeCell = destSh.cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp)` with `Set NextFreeCell = destSh.cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(-1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub sbCopyToDestination()
  
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Set SourceRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("f34:l34")

    Dim NextFreeCell As Range
    Set NextFreeCell = Workbooks("Destination.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp) ' No offset

    With SourceRange
        NextFreeCell.Resize(.Rows.count, 1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        NextFreeCell.Resize(.Rows.count, .Columns.count).Value = .Value
    End With
    
    ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this, and it's still copying the data in after the total row, which is the last row of the sheet. I'm trying to get it to copy it after the last row of data, and before the row of totals. How do I copy in between like that? Is that possible?